# URL generated for Google geocoding works fine in browser but gives 400 error in Python script

Tags: python

I am trying to geocode a column of neighorhood names in a pandas Data Frame. I know that the first url generated works when I copy and paste it into a browser heading, but when I run the api query through the Python script I get an error.

Here's the function:

```
def geo_code(geo_vec):
    partial_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key="+API_KEY+"&address="
    address_list = []
    for g in geo_vec:
        url = partial_api+g+", New York"
        print(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 33, in <module>
    geo_code(geo['Descriptive Name'])
  File "plot.py", line 22, in geo_code
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I have literally copied the generated url from the console where I logged it and pasted it into the browser, and then it works fine. What might urllib2 be doing to make Google call this a bad request? Also it's the first request (first time through the loop) that I get this error, so it's not like it's an api limit error.

I think the problem is because I am using inputs to the url that include adding at the end names with spaces such as "New York City" and "East Harlem". How should I be processing these strings before adding them to the url?

Here's what I tried:

- Using urllib.urlencode({''address' : g}) in the place of "address="+g in the url. This results in the same error even though now the spaces are all replaced with the appropriate + sign.

I'm quite baffled because the url seems fine, and other than url encoding I'm not sure what else I should be doing. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried passing a human **`User-Agent`**?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. No I have not and never had to in the past when using the google api. I've used it with PHP with no header info.

Comment: Did you try using the requests module?

Answer (score 0):

To focus on your code and what is wrong with it. You are not handling your url parameters properly when you are formatting your string in your loop. You should be encoding your url parameters before making your call. Especially when you send "New York", the space will not be accepted.

To resolve this, you should be using [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode).

When using urlencode, you just need to provide a dictionary of key value pairs and urlencode will convert it in to a properly encoded string in the format `a=1&b=2`.

With that, you combine it with your `URL` and that should give you the properly structured URL you need to make your API call. Your adjusted code here ran for me but as expected received an error since I don't have a valid API key.

I've set comments in-line to provide more context.

```
def geo_code(geo_vec):
    # Here simply use your base URL without query params. You can append the ?
    partial_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
    address_list = []

    # Put together the initial structure of your query parameters here as a dictionary
    d = {
        "key": API_KEY,
        "address": ""
    }

    for g in geo_vec:
        # Add your new query param here
        d["address"] = "g{}".format("New York")

        # Call urlencode here to properly structure your query parameters
        url_params = urlencode(d)

        # Properly structure your URL string to make your API call
        url = "{}{}".format(partial_api, url_params)

        # Make API call
        response = urlopen(url)
```

However, as an alternative, and it might make your life easier. It was mentioned in the comments. You should take a look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module.